# Can't Select Elements After Routing Completed in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to validate my form just like [this pen](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI?editors=101). But I'm also using ui-router and my form fields are in another partial page. So I can't select my form as selected as in pen(below).

```
if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }
```

In console I'm getting this error. "TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined".

So what should I do for catch my form fields which are come from partials?

By the way theese are my codes

```
var app = angular.module("App",['ui.router']);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope){

    $scope.Go = function(){
        alert($scope.name);
        if($scope.userForm.$valid){
            alert("Valid");
        }
        else{
            alert("No Valid");
        }
    }

});

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'input.html'
    })
```

});

This is my index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<ui-view></ui-view></div>
```

And this is my partial.html

```
<form name="userForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    <button ng-click="Go()">Go</button></form>
```

Comment: your form name should be `frm` as you want instead of `userForm` inside your input html

Comment: In my codes, I was changed form's name. Reason is not form name.

Comment: @baasr sen then please add your code here..

Comment: I updated codes. @pankajparkar

Comment: Make sure you have novalidate attribute in your form, I believe this is entirely to do with that attribute

Comment: I've also added novalide. But I have same problem. When I use the form without routing, it clearly works. But if I load the form page with angular routing, I can't access it. $scope.userForm can't be catched. @CallumLinington

Comment: try your form torm to point its parent scope like `<form name="$parent.userForm">`

Comment: That is bizarre, i have UI Router and have no trouble reading from the `$scope`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. @pankajparkar

Comment: I will upload the project on my domain. Should it be a problem that I give the link here? @CallumLinington

Comment: No wait, I didn't see that you have the `ng-controller` defined on the outside of the `ui-view`. You need to do what @pankajparkar said, or remove that `ng-controller` and let UI Router handle that.

Comment: @CallumLinington i was wondering, why you said that, then i created a plunkr, it solved issue. I'm Glad :)

Comment: @pankajparkar it was a sneaky little issue, your answer eluded to the problem. I looked and was like what... why define a controller as well :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to point your form to the parent scope like `$parent.userForm` & to get access to the form value do initialize form object inside parent controller of `ui-view` like `$scope.form = {}`. Then we will place all form level values in it.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="Controller">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

**CODE**

```
app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.Go = function() {
    alert($scope.form.name);
    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
      alert("Valid");
    } else {
      alert("No Valid");
    }
  }

});
```

**input.html**

```
<form name="$parent.userForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.name" />
  <button ng-click="Go()">Go</button>
</form>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GOHwBYFKiPj1WL03aP9u?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Yes! that works. But why it always returns "no valid"?

Comment: @BasarSen that was my bad..plunkr contains wrong code, check the updated Plunkr..

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm grateful. That was very important for my job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @pankajparkar said. Or you need to modify your state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'input.html',
        controller: 'Controller'
    });
```

and remove the `ng-controller="Controller"`.

UI Router will automatically load the specified controller for that given state and bind it the `input.html`.